row_number() with alias doesn't work in H2
I'm writing a query using Querydsl which involves the row_number() window function. The following query works fine:
select row_number() over (partition by id)
from example_table ExampleTable

but as soon as I try to alias the selected column then an org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException is thrown
select row_number() over (partition by id) as rownum
from example_table ExampleTable

I'm using io.r2dbc:r2dbc-h2:1.0.0.RELEASE which uses v2.1.214 of H2, com.h2database:h2:2.1.214.
Dialect: MySQL

Turns out the issue was the me using the word rownum. Changing it to rowNumber fixed it, rownum must be a keyword in H2.

In fact it is a function, see: https://www.h2database.com/html/functions.html?search=rownum#rownum

It is a keyword as well: https://h2database.com/html/advanced.html#keywords
